# What's the interface Generator in java

Tags: java

In the book Thinking in Java Chapter Arrays, I find code below in Data Generators:

```
public class CountingGenerator {
            public static class
            Boolean implements Generator<java.lang.Boolean> { /* don't understand */
                private boolean value = false;
                public java.lang.Boolean next() {
                    value = !value;

                    return value;
                }
            }

          /* other code omit */
    }
```

In java docs, I haven't found interface Generator. And eclipse implies error. How to understand the code of that book?

Comment: Look elsewhere in the book. `Generator` must be an interface defined there; it's not part of the standard Java API.

Comment: I think you skipped ahead in the book. Usually you write an interface and then you implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Generator` is an interface write by author in previous pages

you can also write by yourself.

```
// Generator.java
public interface Generator<T> {
    T next();
}
```